# Observable.FromAsync vs Task.ToObservable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Does anyone have a steer on when to use one of these methods over the other. They seem to do the same thing in that they convert from `TPL Task` to an `Observable`.

`Observable.FromAsync` appear to support cancellation tokens which might be the subtle difference that allows the method generating the task to participate in cooperative cancellation if the observable is disposed.

Just wondering if I'm missing something obvious as to why you'd use one over the other.

Thanks

Comment: Check the decompiled source

Comment: I have... I only see cancellation as the difference but I don't follow why that couldn't have been added to .ToObservable in the same way it is for .ToTask. Hence the question, maybe there is another subtle reason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code, it appears that (at least in some flows) that `Observable.FromAsync` calls into `.ToObservable()`*. I am sure the intent that they should be semantically equivalent (assuming you pass the same parameters e.g. Scheduler, CancellationToken etc.).

One is better suited to chaining/fluent syntax, one may read better in isolation. Whichever you coding style favors.

*https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/859e6159cb07be67fd36b18c2ae2b9a62979cb6d/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Async.cs#L727

Comment: It's a good point, I hadn't considered coding style. It also looks like .FromAsync wraps the task in an Observable.Defer  which would make it cold, I don't think .ToObservable does this.

Comment: Correct. I am not a fan of Tasks being hot, but yeah, well, they are.

Answer (score 30):

`Observable.FromAsync` accepts a TaskFactory in the form of `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<TResult>>`,
in this case, the task is only created and executed, when the observable is subscribed to.

Where as `.ToObservable()` requires an already created (and thus started) Task.

Answer (score 28):

@Sickboy answer is correct.

- `Observable.FromAsync()` will start the task at the moment of subscription.
- `Task.ToObservable()` needs an already running task.

One use for `Observable.FromAsync` is to control reentrancy for multiple calls to an async method.

This is an example where these two methods are not equivalent:

```
//ob is some IObservable<T>

//ExecuteQueryAsync is some async method
//Here, ExecuteQueryAsync will run **serially**, the second call will start
//only when the first one is already finished. This is an important property
//if ExecuteQueryAsync doesn't support reentrancy
ob
.Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => ExecuteQueryAsync(x))
.Concat()
.ObserveOnDispatcher()
.Subscribe(action)
```

vs

```
//ob is some IObservable<T>

//ExecuteQueryAsync is some async method
//Even when the `Subscribe` action order will be the same as the first 
//example because of the `Concat`, ExecuteQueryAsync calls could be     
//parallel, the second call to the method could start before the end of the 
//first call. 
.Select(x => ExecuteQueryAsync(x).ToObservable())
.Concat()
.Subscribe(action)
```

Note that on the first example one may need the `ObserveOn()` or `ObserveOnDispatcher()` method to ensure that the `action` is executed on the original dispatcher, since the `Observable.FromAsync` doesn't await the task, thus the continuation is executed on any available dispatcher

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being able to use a CancellationToken, FromAsync wraps in a defer so this allows changing the task logic based upon conditions at the time of subscription.  Note that the Task will not be started, internally task.ToObservable will be called.  The Func does allow you to start the task though when you create it.